# how many times can a spitting cobra spit its venom?

Tags: zoology, snake

exactly how many times can a spitting cobra spit its venom at a predator
it has a small venom sac, so I presume it can only spit once or twice only

Answer (score 1):

*I presume it can only spit once or twice only* An unwise presumption.

> These cobras exhibited distinct control of venom flow with spits averaging 1.7% of the volume of the venom gland, thus enabling the cobras to rapidly expel **over 40 consecutive spits** ... There was no significant difference in the amount of venom spat between the first few spits and the 20th spit, however there was a significant (Student's t-test with unequal variance, p=0.017) decrease in the amount of venom spat between the 20th and 40th spits.

--[Protein variation in the venom spat by the red spitting cobra, Naja pallida (Reptilia: Serpentes)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0041010198002645)

Comment: so it can spray up to 40 times